# Cannot update global state using Context.API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to use Context.API to create a global state and pass it to multiple components. The state will store a few properties including a TwilioToken, device type and a name. I have a component `SignupForm` that renders a button. When the button is clicked, this triggers a function `handleSubmit` that takes a username and passes the username as an argument to another function `setupTwilio`. This function sends the username to an end point that interacts with Twilio Programmable Voice API, sending back a TwilioToken and device type. I then want to update my global state with the Twilio Token and device type and then redirect the user to another page /rooms

Problem is I don't seem to be updating my global state at all, when I console.log(state.TwilioToken) in the component rendered after `handleSubmit` I get null

Here is my context provider:

```
const initialState = {
    nickname: '',
    selectedRoom: null,
    rooms: [],
    createdRoomTopic: '',
    twilioToken: '',
    device: null
};

const RoomContext = createContext(null);

export const RoomContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const[state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    return (
        <RoomContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{children}</RoomContext.Provider>
    )
};

export const useGlobalState = () => {
    const value = useContext(RoomContext)
    if(value === undefined) throw new Error('Please add RoomContextProvider');
    return value;
}
```

My signupform

```
import { useGlobalState } from '../../context/RoomContextProvider';
...
//without useState() I get the error Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

const [state, setState] = useState(useGlobalState()); 
...
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const nickname = user.username;
        setupTwilio(nickname);
        history.push('/rooms');
    }
    const setupTwilio = (nickname) => {
        console.log('inside setupTwilio function', nickname)
        fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice_chat/token/${nickname}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const twilioToken = data.token;
            const device = new Device(twilioToken);
            device.updateOptions(twilioToken, {
                codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
                fakeLocalDTMF: true,
                maxAverageBitrate: 16000
            });
            device.on('error', (device) => {
                console.log("error: ", device)
            });
            setState((state) => {
                return {...state, device, twilioToken}
            });
        })
      ...
    };
    return (
       <button className="button button-primary button-wide-mobile button-sm"
               onClick={handleSubmit}> Start Coding
       </button>

    );
```

When I `console.log` my state in the component rendered I get `null`

```
import { useGlobalState } from '../../context/RoomContextProvider';
...
const [state, setState] = useState(useGlobalState());
console.log('global state token is', state.twilioToken)
```

Comment: can you provide a https://codesandbox.io/ for your code?